# VS Code in Python changes text color of the code if set a return type

Tags: python, themes, visual-studio-code, return-type

The problem is that for example, you have your color theme installed in VS Code, and works just fine, any color theme, but if you set a return type like:

```
def some_function() -> str :
```

instead of just:

```
def some_function():
```

then the color theme stops applying and just turns the text color into white and yellow.
(it happens not only for str obviously)

Has anyone been able to solve that and how?

Comment: I'd run into this issue once.  It was something to do with one of the python extensions.  I disabled all of them and enabled them back one by one looking into what each did avoiding unnecessary ones.  I've seen this happen when there's too many extensions involved serving the same purpose.

Comment: I love you man, the extension that was causing it was "Python for VSCode" (author Thomas Haakon Townsend)

Comment: Thank you so much @AndresDeInnocentiis. The same extension was causing the error.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone runs into this same issue, the extension that was causing it was "Python for VSCode" (author Thomas Haakon Townsend)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Uninstall Python for VSCode from your VS Code, that will solve the issue.